# Is it possible to create a struct whose size is not known at compile time?

Tags: c, memory, data-structures

As the question states I am looking to create a struct in C whose total size I do not know at compile time.

For example, I would like to create a struct that contains a count value and an array with count elements. I know this could be implemented as:

```
typedef struct myStruct{
    int count;
    int *myArray;
} myStruct;
```

However, I want this struct to take up one solid block of memory so I could use `memcpy()` on it at a later point in time. Like this:

```
typedef struct myStruct{
    int count;
    int myArray[count];
} myStruct;
```

Comment: Take a look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910688/c-recommended-style-for-dynamically-sized-structs]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for flexible array members:

```
typedef struct myStruct
{
    int count;
    int myArray[];
} myStruct;
```

Then, when you allocate it later:

```
myStruct *x = malloc(sizeof(myStruct) + n * sizeof(int));
x->count = n;
```

Comment: Why wouldn't the malloc be `(n - 1) * sizeof(int)`? Isn't the `int myArray[]` "size" counted in the `sizeof(myStruct)`?

Comment: @user2246674, no, that's the point of a flexible array member.

Comment: Cool. Can there be multiple flexible array members?

Comment: No, there can not.  Arrays take up space - how would the compiler know how to access the later ones?

Comment: myArray holds a pointer to the next block, so when you memcpy this, you'll still have to update that pointer.

Comment: @Magn3s1um, your statement is absolutely not true.  `myArray` is an array, not a pointer.

Comment: Would `myStruct *x = malloc(sizeof(myStruct) + n * sizeof(x->myArray[0]))` work?  (Somehow use the structure field name rather than `int`?)  Is this preferable or more a style issue?

Comment: Yeah, that should be fine.  You could replace `sizeof(myStruct)` with `sizeof *x`, then, too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. If you use C99, there's [flexible array members](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/MEMxx-C.+Understand+how+flexible+array+members+are+to+be+used). Otherwise, you can do what Microsoft does. Take your original structure definition and map it to an existing block of memory. Reassign the pointer to point just after the structure definition.

Also, the MS approach would allow multiple members with variable size; you just need to properly update each pointer.

(Note: The "MS approach" is just something encountered often in Windows APIs; I don't know if there's an actual term for the practice.)

Comment: OK, I think I'm using the wrong term... flexible array member? Looking for a decent link to explain it...